# How do I install wxPython on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'd like to use wxPython on my Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) computer. (I'm a Tkinter refugee.) I upgraded from Python 2.7.1, then downloaded and installed wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-2.8.12.1-universal-py2.7.dmg. Here's what I get:

```
 Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
 [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
 >>> import wx
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
     import wx
   File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
     from wx._core import *
   File "/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
     import _core_
 ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core_.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

What is this telling me, and what do I do about it???

Answer (score 41):

[Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) provides wxWidgets 2.9 in full 64bit glory including wxWidgets.

`brew install wxmac`

Comment: this is not enough. I'm still gettint that error. You also need to also: `brew install wxpython`

Comment: Yeah, as @CpILL says, do `brew install wxpython`. It will automatically install `wxmac` as a dependency.

Comment: Just a heads up, that it installs a lot of packages.

Answer (score 19):

I suggest:

```
brew install wxpython
```

since wxpython installs wxmac, no need to install it seperately:

```
brew install wxmac
Warning: wxmac-3.0.2_2 already installed
```

Comment: That did it for me

Comment: in my mac I have python and python3; if I run brew install wxpython it will install wxpython for python (2.7.xx) but I need it for python3. How to do ?

Comment: @ErnestPoldrige good point. I think an alias might help but can't guarantee it. For example, before running brew install, run alias python=python3 (given python3 is in your PATH).

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want is a cocoa API based wxPython, then you don't have to worry about architecture.

Here is a link to the download for wxPython 2.9: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython2.9-osx-2.9.4.0-cocoa-py2.7.dmg,

and here is the page that explains it: http://wxpython.org/download.php.

Answer (score 3):

Use brew* to install wxmac using the following command.

brew install --python wxmac --devel

once you install the wxmac create a symbolic link between the installed wx to the python library.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx

I Hope it will be helpful for future installers.

*if you do not have Brew installed prior, install it using the following command:
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Comment: It's indeed `brew install wxpython`, and the `wxmac` will be installed as part of `wxpython` installation. Also no need (in my case) to do symlink, since `brew` will do the job for you, if Homebrew's site-packages is in your python `sys.path` .

Answer (score 1):

Mike's link is a great link to the answer, but just for completeness...

wxPython uses wxMac, which uses Carbon, which is limited to just 32 bit executables.
However Python2.7(64bit) comes with a python-32 command.

```
$ python-32
>> import wx
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct version of wxPython. Not just the right Python version, but the right bit version two: 32 vs. 64. This sounds a lot like this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wxpython-users/NQEY2SUC058