# Python wx import fails Mac OS X 10.9.5 using Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, anaconda

I installed Python wx from the official website. However when I try to import wx, I got the following error message:

```
import wx Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1,
in <module> ImportError: No module named wx
```

I tried to run 32bit and 64bit version, but it still does not work. I am using the following version  for python:

```
Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jan 10 2014, 11:23:15) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
```

Comment: check which folder your wxpython installed. And check you pythonpath with `sys.path` in your conda environment. If the wx folder is not in the pythonpath you should add it manually or change the wx folder where conda can see it

Comment: also, your conda environment is 64 bits so you **must** use wxPython 64 bits

Comment: How can I check whether wx is installed? I see a lot of wx folders, but I don't know which one to add! I added all, but it still does not work. @joaquin I am using the 64 version

Comment: I am not OSX user. You should look for the folder where the wx code and libraries are. But I can not help more. Maybe you can find something here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205317/how-do-i-install-wxpython-on-mac-os-x

Comment: It was an error due to Anaconda. You have to install the package through anaconda by using 'conda install wxpython'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anaconda is not linked to the default python folder, so whether brew nor the installer could be linked to the anaconda distribution.

```
conda install wxpython
```

does the trick