# Can't Install wxPython with Brew

Tags: python, macos

I've tried to install wxPython on my mac with brew, using the command suggested at [How do I install wxPython on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205317/how-do-i-install-wxpython-on-mac-os-x/12514960#12514960) by rajmohanloganathan

```
brew install --python wxmac --devel
```

That seems to work, but when I try setting up the symlink, I don't find a folder corresponding to /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx.  In my /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.02/lib/, there is no python2.7 directory. The closest I come is /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/3.02/lib/wx, and linking to that doesn't work.

When I brew doctor, I get a warning that python is installed in /Library and that this may cause problems with other installations.  Is that the root of my problem?  How do I go about fixing matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice I looked at is outdated.

```
brew install wxpython
```

is all you need.