# Python wx via Homebrew

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having issues install Python wx on my Mac. Here's what I did:

```
brew install wxpython
```

which gave this Caveat:

```
Caveats
Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
please run:
  mkdir -p /Users/snowcrash/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
  echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' 
  >> /Users/snowcrash/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

So I ran the 2 commands from the Terminal as suggested:

```
mkdir -p /Users/snowcrash/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages 
>> echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")'
```

but when I try to `import wx` I am getting:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core_.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core_.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

and this doesn't seem to help:

[How do I install wxPython on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205317/how-do-i-install-wxpython-on-mac-os-x)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you may have entered the second command wrong. The *full* command is: `echo 'import [snip]' >> /Users/snowcrash/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth` ... Are you sure you got the part after the `>>`? Because that's not in your second code-block (and it's formatted confusingly in the first code block)...

Comment: Ah - good catch! Now a different error. Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to do this:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool no
```