# SimpleCV on OS X 10.10.1 Import Error

Tags: python, simplecv

I installed SimpleCV on my Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite ,

```
$ pip freeze
PIL==1.1.7
PySAL==1.8.0
SimpleCV==1.3
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==2.3.1
mercurial==3.2.1
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.9.1
pygame==1.9.2a0
pyparsing==2.0.3
scipy==0.14.0
svgwrite==1.1.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

and when I want Run it , It says :

```
Last login: Sat Dec  6 19:04:49 on ttys001
Amirhosseins-MacBook-Pro:~ amirhosseingholami$ simplecv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/simplecv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('SimpleCV==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'simplecv')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2394, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2108, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV-1.3-py2.7.egg/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from SimpleCV.base import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV-1.3-py2.7.egg/SimpleCV/base.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pygame as pg
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

So What is the problem ?
Please Help me solve this problem.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8

Comment: It's not really due to SimpleCV. Also, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606964/no-matching-architecture-in-universal-wrapper-problem-in-wxpython