# Running in 32-bit mode permanently

Tags: python, macos

I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to force my mac to run in 32-bit mode permanently. Currently I've been using this piece of code:
`arch -i386 /usr/bin/python`
to change it but once I exit python in the terminal it switches back to 64. The reason I want to do this is so I can install pygame. I've already installed it but only in 64-bit mode. I'm not sure if I also need to install it in 32-bit mode for it to work properly. At the moment it says the module does not exist.

Comment: You want to make the entire OS run in 32bit mode?

Comment: @user1064913: I think you might do best on http://apple.stackexchange.com, what do you think?

Comment: We should also note that this is following on from [Installing Pygame for Mac OS X 10.6.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275808/installing-pygame-for-mac-os-x-10-6-8)

Comment: I'm not even sure if this will fix my problem. Maybe if I could just always run python in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Have you thought of using a virtual machine?

Comment: @user1064913: have you tried just doing what they say at http://pygame.org/install.html? Things like http://geoffford.wordpress.com/2009/01/20/pygame-on-os-x-leopard/#bullets may help, too.

Comment: Alright, so pygame now shows up in the modules list but I can only use it if I'm running in 32-bit mode which means I can only use python version 2.6.

Comment: Finally got it to work even though I can only run it in 2.6. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

For the built in python, you can set the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` environment variable to `1`. For non-built-in Python, you can just install 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

See this question: [How do I force Python to be 32-bit on Snow Leopard and other 32-bit/64-bit questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest)

Answer (score 0):

With the default python install you will get both the 32 and 64 bit versions. The 32 bit version can be called from the terminal with `python2.7-32` or `python-32`.