# ImportError when trying to install pygame 1.9.1 (32bit) on 64 bit Mac 10.6 machine with Python 2.7.2

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit, pygame

***Update: Here are the errors I am getting:

```
>>> import pygame

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

>>> arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.7

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> arch -i386 python2.7

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> arch -i386 /usr/local/bin/python2.7

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> arch -i386 python

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If some of these are Unix commands that I should be entering somewhere else, please let me know.

I am trying to install pygame 1.9.1 (32bit) on 64 bit Mac 10.6 machine with Python 2.7.2 (I also have Python 3.2 installed on the same machine).  I am using the Python versions downloaded from the website, not the preinstalled versions.  I tried the following solutions (from here: [How do I force Python to be 32-bit on Snow Leopard and other 32-bit/64-bit questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest)), but they didn't work for me:

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

(I also tried with renaming the last string python2.7 and just python)

I have entered all of these 'solutions' in the Python 2.7.2 shell.  Please let me know if you have any other ideas and thanks so much for the help.  I would appreciate if you could explain how to implement the solution in detail and what the solution does.

Comment: What's the error? What doesn't work?

Comment: Please share an actual *error message*. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you enter them in the Python shell? Those are Unix shell commands.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I added the errors I am getting above.  If I am entering commands in Python that should be Unix shell commands, please let me know.  I have no idea to enter Unix commands, but I can try to figure it out.  I am obviously a newbie, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments of the answer you linked to, solution 1 only works with the Apple-supplied Pythons, not Pythons installed from elsewhere.  The Apple-installed Pythons are accessed from `/usr/bin`; generally, Pythons installed from `python.org` or elsewhere will be accessible as just `python2.7` (no `/usr/bin`) or possibly as `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.  Try  solution 2 using one of those paths, i.e.:

```
arch -i386 python2.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Should I run these commands in the Unix shell or the Python shell?  Sorry, I am a newbie :)