# Error importing MySQLdb in Python 2.7.2 on Mac OSx 10.8.1

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion

I recently upgraded to OSx Mountain Lion (10.8) and shortly after to 10.8.1.  I was attempting to do an "import MySQLdb" and ran into the following errors:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.py:3: UserWarning: Module _mysql was already imported from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.pyc, but /Users/jlk/Software_Downloads/MySQL-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3 is being added to sys.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jlk/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jlk/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Not really sure what is wrong or how to fix it.  I have googled around, but am unable to find any answers pertaining to osx 10.8.1 with this issue.  It states at the end that its the "wrong architecture", but I know that what I have installed is the OSx version of the module.  The only difference I see is that it says its for 10.8, but this is the most current version of the module.

For reference:

OS:  OSx Mountain Lion 10.8.1
Pyhon version:  2.7.2

Any ideas?

Regards,

Jeff

Comment: Ok, I have done more searching and so far, everything that I have found for interacting with MySQL via python seems to want to use the MySQLdb module, which, as stated below, is not currently compatible with the 2.7.x+ version of Python.  

Does anyone have any ideas as to how else I could interface with mysql using Python, not using that module?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the python interpreter you're using and the _mysql.so were built for different sets of architectures, e.g. one is i386 only and the other one 32/64 bit fat. You can check that by running `file /path/to/your python interpreter` and `file /path/to_mysql.so` and comparing the output.

Can you rebuild MySQLdb and make sure pip / easy_install uses the correct python interpreter? Also, if you haven't done so already, upgrade your Xcode version and its command line tools to avoid the usual spew of build errors.

**edit:** I could reproduce this on 10.7 with Apple's stock Python 2.7.1. The problem really is an architecture mismatch between the python interpreter, MySQLdb and the MySQL server. Python is a 32/64bit fat build, the MySQL version I have installed is 32bit only. MySQLdb looks at MySQL's architecture when building, so I got a 32bit only _mysql.so. When importing the module in python which probably runs in 64bit mode, the error occurs.

I think installing and running a 64bit version of MySQL and the rebuilding MySQL-Python should solve this, or you could [force Python to run in 32bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest).

Comment: I checked the versions as you suggested and they are all correct.  After I had upgraded to 10.8 I did re-install xcode and also installed the command line tools.

I actually JUST found out via the sourceforge site for this module (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) that it appears Python 2.7 and above versions are coming soon.  I am gathering that that may actually be the issue.

Comment: Wow, I can actually reproduce this. I'm on 10.7 with Apple's stock Python 2.7.1 and I'm seeing the same issue.