# MySQLdb for Python 2.7 on OSX 10.8.2 and BOTH are 64 bit

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

Here's my problem: I can't Get MySQLdb for python working. Most of the other posts regarding this have cited having different architectures of MySQL/Python. I checked, and they're both 64 bit. I have Python 2.7.2 (standard OS X) and the latest MySQL, OS X 10.8.2.

**my original error logs:**

Trying to import MySQL db gives me this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

This might be helpful as well, the console output while I install mysql-python 1.2.4b4

```
xxx-MBP:MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 me$ sudo python setup.py clean
running clean
removing 'build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7' (and everything under it)
xxx-MBP:MySQL-python-1.2.4b4 me$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql.so -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_mysql_exceptions.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
copying build/lib.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/times.py -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql_exceptions.py to _mysql_exceptions.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py to connections.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py to CLIENT.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/CR.py to CR.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/ER.py to ER.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py to FIELD_TYPE.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py to FLAG.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py to REFRESH.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/converters.py to converters.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py to cursors.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/release.py to release.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/MySQLdb/times.py to times.pyc
creating stub loader for _mysql.so
byte-compiling build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/_mysql.py to _mysql.pyc
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
copying MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
removing '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
Extracting MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
MySQL-python 1.2.4b4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
Finished processing dependencies for MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
```

Comment: Interesting Note, I cleaned my install and then followed these  (  http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/02/21/python-mysql-connections-on-mac-os/) directions (the macports part didn't work for me), specifically I rebuilt using 64bit flags during the build process and then reinstalled.    NOW SOMETHING WIERD HAPPENS.  Import MySQLdb WORKS FROM THE TERMINAL, but NOT from within a code editor.

Comment: Also of Note, /library/python contains folders for 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7, but the 2.7 one has stuff in it. WITHIN 2.7 (/library/python/2.7/) I have a multiple egg files, a MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg, AND a MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg, and both of THOSE have the same files inside them…should I delete one? which one should I keep? I'm so extremely frustrated guys.

Comment: ALSO OF NOTE: If I do control-| while in python in terminal, it exits out, but I get an OSX window that says Python quit unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you. That one line for the terminal has made be very happy. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I THINK I GOT IT! Here's what I did.

OK this has been extremely frustrating.

What finally made it work was doing this in the terminal :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

But there was alot of other stuff before that. I mixed the directions from two sources:

[How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)
and
http://birdhouse.org/blog/2009/02/21/python-mysql-connections-on-mac-os/

I used the first to clean python and change the build files…
I used the second to add 64 bit flags to install and build…

Then I used an answer at [Error importing MySQLdb in Python 2.7.2 on Mac OSx 10.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327737/error-importing-mysqldb-in-python-2-7-2-on-mac-osx-10-8-1)  (which was the final thing that made it work.)

to set me over the edge.

I’m not sure exactly what made a difference because I did SO MANY THINGS. I deleted a bunch of stuff from the 2.7 python folder….and other things. But the only thing i can be sure of is that mixing the directions from those two sources made a difference. Thanks for all the help, guys….lol I hope this saves somebody a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I have listed the 4 configuration impediments that i faced, I have listed them.

export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
installing command line tools from xcode preferences/downloads
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib