# python-mysqldb AGAIN Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, mysql-python

Took me a days to get mysqldb working on Snow Leopard so this time round I did a completely clean install of the operating system and carefully followed the various instructions on installation to try and get my django development environment working.

```
brew install mysql 
sudo pip intall django
sudo pip install mysql-python

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
sudo export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Mysql and django working fine, but if I try to import MySQLdb or do a syncdb I get this error:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
>>>
```

Have been googling for a day now with no success and really need to get back to work!  Any suggestions very welcome.

(also tried to install the mysql python-connector here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/ but there is no osx version and other instructions seem to imply you need the right version for your version of python no platform so I didn't pursue that further.)

**Update**

Having run brew doctor cleanly am getting these errors on trying the --universal option:

```
iMacs-iMac:~ phoebebr$ brew install -v  mysql --universal
==> Downloading http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.13.tar.gz/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.13.com
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mysql-5.6.13.com
==> cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/man -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/doc/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/info -DINSTALL_MYSQLSHAREDIR=share/mysql -DWITH_SSL=yes -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DSYSCONFDIR=/usr/local/etc -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_READLINE=yes -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES='i386;x86_64'
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/man -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/doc/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.13/share/info -DINSTALL_MYSQLSHAREDIR=share/mysql -DWITH_SSL=yes -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DSYSCONFDIR=/usr/local/etc -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_READLINE=yes -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES='i386;x86_64'
-- Running cmake version 2.8.11.2
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 4.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.2/share/cmake/Modules/Platform/Darwin.cmake:190 (message):
  CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET is '10.8' but CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT:

   ""

  is not set to a MacOSX SDK with a recognized version.  Either set
  CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT to a valid SDK or set CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to
  empty.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (PROJECT)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
HEAD: b9b09cb1a620cd5ddafffc22d56a34e160bfc3f4
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.8.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.3
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
X11: 2.7.4 => /opt/X11
==> ENV
CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe
LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET: 10.8
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.8:/usr/lib/pkgconfig
OBJC: /usr/bin/clang
PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/Library/Contributions/cmd
CPATH: /usr/local/include

Error: mysql did not build
Logs:       /Users/phoebebr/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql/CMakeCache.txt
```

Did find this related to cmake error but this is really getting beyond my technical ability!
http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/OSX-deployment-target-confusion-for-2-8-10-td7582284.html
Looking at the mysql site it's not obvious to me how to install universal directly.

**UPdate 2**

This page was useful: [Error importing MySQLdb in Python 2.7.2 on Mac OSx 10.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327737/error-importing-mysqldb-in-python-2-7-2-on-mac-osx-10-8-1)

So installed mysql again without -- universal and checked the architecture of everything like this:

```
iMacs-iMac:~ phoebebr$ which python
/usr/bin/python
iMacs-iMac:bin phoebebr$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

iMacs-iMac:mysql phoebebr$ which mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
iMacs-iMac:mysql phoebebr$ file /usr/local/bin/mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

and still getting the same error.

```
iMacs-iMac:~ phoebebr$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
>>>
```

Comment: Back to only having sqlite on my mac then.  Someone has suggested switching to Postgresql so might give that a go.

Comment: Have you checked if your binaries are built for the right architecture? MacOSX keeps i386 and x86_64 binaries around, and sometimes in arbitrary combinations. Have you tried macports? I tried homebrew, but I was very disappointed about its inconsistency over time, so I switched back.

Comment: As this is a relatively new machine and a new install I could be confident everything was 64bit.  Homebrew knows it's 64 bit, .bash_profile has export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  Is there anything else I should have done?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known Bug](http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=87704) -- the mysql-python package is built only for 64-bit at the moment.

Comment: Have tried to be consistently 64bit but thanks for finding this bug, had not come across it when googling myself.

Comment: I am marking this down because it's not a canonical answer. Neither it brings a solution to the table.

Comment: @Believe2014 if it makes you feel better feel free to vote down.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mysql with the universal flag to avoid architecture binary mismatching.  I would go through a complete uninstall of all related software and then clean installation of all related software.

brew install mysql --universal

Comment: Reinstalling mysql with universal flag does not help. I even have MySql 32 bit installed on my Mac, same errors still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a work around and not adress your issue, but if you have an old laptop/computer lying around, install a light linux distro on it and set that up as your sql database server.

Thats the way I set up my dev enviroments anyways so they reflect "real world" connectivity via the slight delay the network communication incurs.

Comment: It does not matter where the MySql installed, the errors occur and prevent the main program from proceeding.