# Forcing 32 bit Python on MAC 10.7 or 10.8

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, platypus

I have MAC OS X 10.8 and i have updated my python to version 2.7.3 using Python's official binary from their website.

I am trying to run a python script which needs to be executed using 32 bit python.

How can i force to run 32-bit python instead of 64-bit?

Command file /usr/bin/python gives me following output.

```
Alis-Mac:~ ali$ file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I have also tried the following.

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

But this has not even helped because now, i have custom python i guess.

My script has wxpython code in it and i am building app for OSX using platypus so, i have to force my script to run with 32-bit python. Please help.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest
I belive you can find what you need there.

Comment: I have already checked that one before posting this question. It didn't help.

Comment: Meet the same problem with you when I deploy my development on Mountain Lion :-(

Comment: You've tried `arch -i386 /usr/bin/python` and that doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried `$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes`?

Answer (score 0):

for now install virtualbox and develop your app in a 32Bit Ubuntu

you can also install pycharm which can allow you to debug through vagrant