# How do I force my code to use 32-bit Python in a virtual environment?

Tags: python

Title pretty much says it all.  Python 2.7.8, OSX 10.8.5  Already tried (separately) all the methods on:

[How do I force Python to be 32-bit on Snow Leopard and other 32-bit/64-bit questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest)

```
arch -i386 /usr/local/bin/python
```

and

`defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes`

and

`export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes`

When I jump into the interpreter and run `import platform; platform.architecture()` I still get

`('64bit', '')`
for each one.

`sys.maxsize > 2**32` returns `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`platform.architecture()` is unreliable on OSX, to be sure you're still runing 64 bit and not 32 you should run `sys.maxsize > 2**32`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html#platform.architecture

Comment: That returns True, which if I'm understanding the docs correctly means it's running 64-bit.  How do I force 32?

Comment: Ah, running it in `arch -i386 /usr/local/bin/python` works.  Thanks!