# Setting up pypy sandbox on ubuntu

Tags: python, sandbox, pypy

This is the error I am getting while setting up pypy sandbox on ubuntu 14.
Please help if you can find any clue

```
(my-pypy-env)sterilistic@sterilistic:~/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/pypy/goal$ ../../rpython/bin/rpython -O2 --sandbox targetpypystandalone.py
[translation:info] 2.7.10 (5f8302b8bf9f, Nov 18 2015, 10:46:49)
[translation:info] [PyPy 4.0.1 with GCC 4.6.3]
[platform:msg] Set platform with 'host' cc=None, using cc='gcc', version='Unknown'
[translation:info] Translating target as defined by targetpypystandalone
[platform:execute] gcc -c -O3 -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-unused /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.c -o /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.o
[platform:execute] gcc /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.o -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -lrt -o /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest
[platform:execute] gcc -c -O3 -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-unused /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.c -o /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.o
[platform:execute] gcc /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest.o -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -lrt -o /tmp/usession-release-4.0.1-9/gcctest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../rpython/bin/rpython", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sterilistic/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/rpython/translator/goal/translate.py", line 217, in main
    targetspec_dic, translateconfig, config, args = parse_options_and_load_target()
  File "/home/sterilistic/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/rpython/translator/goal/translate.py", line 156, in parse_options_and_load_target
    targetspec_dic = load_target(targetspec)
  File "/home/sterilistic/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/rpython/translator/goal/translate.py", line 98, in load_target
    mod = __import__(specname)
  File "targetpypystandalone.py", line 13, in <module>
    from rpython.rlib import rthread
  File "/home/sterilistic/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/rpython/rlib/rthread.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rpython.rtyper.lltypesystem import rffi, lltype, llmemory
  File "/home/sterilistic/Desktop/Coderunner/pypy-4.0.1-src/rpython/rtyper/lltypesystem/rffi.py", line 1077, in <module>
    maxint, sizeof(llmemory.Address)))
AssertionError: Mixed configuration of the word size of the machine:
    the underlying Python was compiled with maxint=2147483647,
    but the C compiler says that 'void *' is 8 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C compiler is what defines how many bytes your sandbox can compute. Due to limit of 8 bytes, this appears to be code designed for a 32-bit machine. From [this](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/rfkelly/pypyjs_update_a_proof_of_concept_jit/) webpage:

> PyPy/RPython makes a lot of platform/architecture decisions based on the version of python that you use to run the build. Since emscripten provides a 32-bit runtime environment, you'll need to run the build using a 32-bit version of python. (I build in a 32-bit Ubuntu VM to achieve this).

Essentially, you need to run a 32-bit version of Python. I am uncertain how to do this on Windows and Linux, but [here is a Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088569/how-do-i-force-python-to-be-32-bit-on-snow-leopard-and-other-32-bit-64-bit-quest) on how to do it on a mac, which may give you some starting points. Your best bet is to run a VM with a [32-bit version of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)--just select `32-bit` instead of `64-bit` on the download page.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks man! but had no luck. checked python architecture version, its 32 bit only.

Answer (score 0):

You're running PyPy 4.0.1 32-bit, and it is calling the C compiler, which is gcc or clang 64-bit.  You need to make these two consistent, for example by downloading and running PyPy 4.0.1 64-bit.