# ignoring file ....libgcc.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

Tags: macos, linker, x86-64, llvm-gcc

Basically, I want to run a .cpp and link several .a files and gcc,fortran. The command is as

> g++ -L/Users/myhome/Ipopt-3.10.0/build/lib -lipopt  -L/Users/myhome/lcoinmumps -lpthread -framework vecLib  **-L/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1** -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran **-lgcc_static -lcc_kext -lgcc**  -lSystem  -framework vecLib -framework vecLib -lm  -ldl -o cpp_example cpp_example.cpp

The error shows as

> ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /**Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/libgcc_static.a**, **file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)**: /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/libgcc_static.a ignoring file /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/libgcc.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/libgcc.a

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MyNLP::MyNLP()", referenced from:
      _main in ccY99KRH.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

As bold text shows, the error seems to be I am running on 32bit kernel or CPU. But I am using x86_64: i've changed boost.plist according to [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6/5/) and 'about mac' proves clearly that both hardware and software I am using now is 64bit.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455720/mac-osx-10-6-compiler-a-puzzling-experience-with-32-vs-64-bit) seems to have explained that mac architecture(?) somehow could not be recognized 64 bits.

But when I add files (.a .cpp .h) into Xcode and run the project together, it works fine.

Anyone knows why the command line doesn't work? Why my libgcc(i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2) could not be recognized as 64bit version? And most importantly, how to get commands to work?

BTW, my system is lion 10.7.4

Comment: Just to make sure, are you _trying_ to compile 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  I am trying to compile 64bit. But the error message said that the libgcc files "was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)".

Comment: The x64 libs are in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64`, but I strangely don't see libgcc_static.a there.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Try 'cd /Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1' directly, not the Developer folder under Applications directory. The Developer folder is at same directory level as Applications folder :)